# How do I make an object bounce off the edges in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make my 'Enemy' bounce off all the boundaries. For example, when the Enemy collides with the left, right, top and bottom of the screen, it should change direction.

This is my current code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

struct Physics {
    static let Enemy: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let BorderCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    let BottomCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
    let BallCategory   : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4

}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var Enemy = SKSpriteNode()
    var gameStarted = Bool()
    var gameState = "running"
    var destX : CGFloat = 0.0
    var destY : CGFloat = 0.0
    var score = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        borderBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = borderBody
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main().bounds     // get the screen size
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width                  //get the width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height                //get the height


        Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "red2")
        Enemy.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 70)
        Enemy.position = (CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 6 - Enemy.frame.width, y: self.frame.height / 10))

        Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Enemy.frame.height / 2)
        Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.Enemy
        //Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.Ground | Physics.wall
        //Enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics.Ground | Physics.wall
        Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true


        self.addChild(Enemy)
        Enemy.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 50)

        if (Enemy.position.x == screenWidth) {
            Enemy.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: -50, dy: 0)      // change direction at edge DOESN'T WORK
        }

        if(Enemy.position.y == screenHeight){
            Enemy.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -50)      //change direction at edge  DOESN'T WORK
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, based on your code I've written a working bouncing sprite. It uses the physics-engine to achieve this, rather than manually changing the direction (which I guess is how you should go about doing this).

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    borderBody.friction = 0
    borderBody.categoryBitMask = Physics.wall
    physicsBody = borderBody
    let enemy = enemySprite(size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 70), position: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2))
    addChild(enemy)
    let force = SKAction.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 300, dy: 300) , duration: 0.1)
    enemy.run(force)
}

func enemySprite(size: CGSize, position: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode {
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red(), size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 80))
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2)
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemy.frame.height / 2) // A bit silly with circle, but you seem to have an image for this use
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.enemy
    enemy.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    enemy.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.wall
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    return enemy
}
```

A question to consider is also how you set up the scene? Is the scene-size the same as the view-size? Otherwise the scene's physicsBody will not make the ball bounce where you expect it to...

Comment: I'm very new to programming in swift so forgive me for any ridiculous statements. This only gets the enemy to bounce off the sides once. I was hoping that the enemy would continue to bounce around the screen. Is there any way of doing this? Also when I set the position of the enemy to be the frame width / 2 and the frame height / 2, this does not place the enemy in the centre off the screen. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Unless you are modifying any of the above elsewhere this code makes the enemy bounce until the "end of times". (I've built it to confirm this myself). Perhaps an answer to _my_ question in the bottom of my reply could lead you on the way: How do you create the scene and what is its size (relative to the screen)?.

Answer (score 0):

It won't (in most cases) because of your conditions - using equal to operators instead of greater/lower than.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        // Create enemy with physics body attached and add it to the scene
        let enemy = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
        enemy.name = "enemy"
        enemy.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: enemy.size)
        enemy.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
        enemy.physicsBody!.mass = 0.1
        enemy.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 150, dy: 0)
        addChild(enemy)
    }

    override func didSimulatePhysics() {
        let enemy = childNodeWithName("enemy")!

        if (enemy.position.x > size.width && enemy.physicsBody!.velocity.dx > 0)
            || (enemy.position.x < 0 && enemy.physicsBody!.velocity.dx < 0) {
            enemy.physicsBody!.velocity.dx *= -1
        }
    }
}
```